# Cambiar valor de una columna SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando un proyecto en laravel y MYSQL, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma que si el stock de sea diferente a 0 el estado pase a ser 'no disponible', en caso que no la haya con MYSQL, hay algún gestor de DDBB que me lo permita?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste haciendo un trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el modelo `Producto` podés crear un metodo que te devuelva el stock de cada producto, entonces en lugar de hacer `$producto->stock` harías `$producto->inStock()`.

```
/** Devuelve la cantidad en stock y si no hay disponibles devuelve "No disponible" */
public function inStock()
{
    return $this->stock === 0 ? 'No Disponible' : $this->stock;
}
```